# Fazer código só funcionar em Desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço um código, JQuery/JavaScript funcionar apenas em Desktop? Ou seja, em celulares e tablets, não quero ele funcionando... Com CSS uso o Media Query, mas com JavaScript fico meio perdido.

Obrigado!

Comment: Qual é a utilidade disso? Do ponto de vista do usuário, é uma limitação arbitrária (e irritante). Do ponto de vista de segurança, é inútil, já que qualquer solução vai depender do navegador do usuário honrar algum padrão que pode ser burlado facilmente.

Comment: Pablo, é que tem efeitos que não quero que funcione no celular, é diferente, popups também. Quero deixar o celular o mais simples possível. Tenho uma loja, são usuários comuns e leigos. Com o Media Query do CSS, não tem como burlar, pôs em tal tamanho o efeito não aparece ou é diferente. Então, só queria a mesma coisa pro JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o caso depender do **tamanho do ecrã**, podes apenas fazer:

```
if ($(window).width() > 960) {
   alert('ecrã é maior que 960');
}
```

Se o caso depender mesmo de ser um **navegador desktop** ou não, podes fazer desta maneira como sugerido [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15732847/3624981) do Stack Overflow em inglês:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isDesktop = (function() {
        return !('ontouchstart' in window) // works on most browsers 
        || !('onmsgesturechange' in window); // works on ie10
    })();
    //edit, if you want to use this variable outside of this closure, or later use this:
    window.isDesktop = isDesktop;
    if( isDesktop ){ /* desktop things */ }
});
```

Comment: Meu PC tem ecrã sensível a toque. Essa verificação pelo `ontouchstart` faria com que o servidor me desse uma experiência de telemóvel em um ecrã de quinze polegadas.

Comment: Fiquei com a do $(window).width(); Achei melhor, e acho que vai funcionar igual o Media Query do CSS.

Comment: Verdade @Renan , por acaso não pensei nisso.